# Style a Wordpress Post date where the DAY is larger than the MONTH

Tags: wordpress, date

currently, I have:

```
<abbr class="date time published" title="2013-11-13T02:00:52+0000">13 Nov</abbr>
```

I need to style the day larger than the month, say with a  like this:

```
<abbr class="date time published" title="2013-11-13T02:00:52+0000"><span>13</span> Nov</abbr>
```

But wordpress lumps it as a string under post_date. Any ideas how I can get FURTHER control?

Comment: `list($day,$month)=explode(' ',$post_date);`, then do whatever you like.

Comment: Here's what I found works for me: 

    $post_ts    =  strtotime( $post->post_date );      
    $post_day  = date('j', $post_ts);
    $post_month =  date('M', $post_ts );
    echo ('<p class="date-day">'.$post_day.'</p>');
    echo ('<p class="date-month">'.$post_month.'</p>');